# Italian passport: Do I need visa for 1 week holidays in Singapore

Tags: visas, singapore, italian-citizens

I've Italian passport, I live in the Netherlands: do I need a visa for 1 week holidays in Singapore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of nationals requiring a visa can be found on the [Singapore's Immigration & Checkpoint Authority Visa Requirements page](http://www.ica.gov.sg/page.aspx?pageid=96).

Since Italy is not on the list you won't require a visa, if you [don't intend to stay over 90 days](http://www.staralliance.com/en/services/visa-and-health/).