# Filipino in Japan, going to visit Singapore

Tags: singapore, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino, holding a student visa here in Japan and I would like to visit Singapore for tourist just for maybe less than a week. Now, do I need to apply for visa or if not, what do I directly have to do?

Comment: Whilst the question is for a different nationality, this answer will probably be helped http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/49821/1820

Answer (score 2):

**No, you don't need a visa**

You can check on [this website](http://www.ica.gov.sg/services_centre_overview.aspx?pageid=252&secid=165) of the immigration authority whether you need a visa. As a Filipino-citizen, you do not need to apply for a visa beforehand for short term visit.

According to [VisaHQ](https://singapore.visahq.com/requirements/Philippines/resident-Japan/), you can stay for up to 30 days.